# how can I bind the laser's click to thumbleft? seeking to resolve conflict between laser clicks and teleport

Tags: aframe

is there a way to bind laser_click_event to ex. thumbupstart? Also for me laser component conflicts w teleport, how can we fix this? Also all trackpad buttons emit click (w laser), how can we fix this? Also I want to enable or disable the laser controls click events with mouseenter on all entities or disable teleport so it only works when if its mouseenter on the ground, how can I do this?

this is all summed up as one question: how do I resolve the conflict between laser clicks and teleport?

see examples of my comically failed efforts here (with code snippets and comments

https://glitch.com/~marked-carriage

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Vive to test it, but i can propose two options:

1) [teleport-controls](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls) - You can change the button, which launches the teleport:

```
button: {default: 'trackpad', oneOf: ['trackpad', 'trigger', 'grip', 'menu']}
```

For example: `teleport-controls="button: grip"`

2) [laser-controls](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/laser-controls.js#L72-L75) - in the source code, you can see how is the cursor configured:

```
'gearvr-controls': {
  cursor: {downEvents: ['trackpaddown'], upEvents: ['trackpadup']},
  raycaster: {origin: {x: 0, y: 0.0005, z: 0}}
},
```

Although it's not customizable, if you fork `a-frame`, or copy the `laser-controls` source code, you could switch it to any other event (`triggerup`, `thumbup`).

Comment: Why is my laser not appearing? <a-entity modified-laser-controls raycaster="objects: .clickable; .links; far: 50" line="color: red; opacity: 0.75"></a-entity>

Comment: Latest version of my script I can’t figure it out. Please help!

I am getting an error inside VR that says “errorScript error”

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/micah1/aframe@db618bd8810bef1667ad10c6b59eb30d420ce9ed/src/components/laser-controls.js

Comment: Folks can try it out at, if they have standalone VR, (like Oculus Go) but my “daser” script designed to replace the laser still does not work. Please help if you can. http://splendid-noise.glitch.me